# How to create SQLite Database dynamically? Using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

I need to create a SQLite Database dynamically when script is ran. And it checks if database exists, if it doesn't, it create one for you.

I used this code but doesn't seem work

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec(`sqlite3 test.db`, (err, stdout, stderr)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout)
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr)
})
```

Comment: Hello @Ayush, maybe you can try this approach [setup SQLite on Nodejs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sqlite-with-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04)